# YouTube video with iframe doesn't display properly with Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, youtube

I am trying to play a YouTube video on a website using this code:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
 src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zdHZSEOtfuE" allowfullscreen>
 You can find the video  
 <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zdHZSEOtfuE">here.</a>            
</iframe>
```

It works well with Safari and IE, but I am having trouble with Chrome. While I am developing and the HTML file is on my computer, the video display properly. But once I put it on the server, my page just shows a white frame. It doesn't even show the alternative link. I tried on several computers with several versions of Chrome, but get the same result every time. Do you have any idea what causes this and how to fix it?

Comment: Just a guess: is the page served from your server over https rather than http?  If so, and if your Chrome settings disallow mixed content, that might explain it.

Comment: Open the console and check if there's any error. If yes, let us know what kind of error and we could help you

Comment: @phari That's it. I replaced `http` by `https` in the `src` link and now it works.